# Adding new subscription options and decommissioning existing ones for an app in Google Play

Tags: google-play, google-play-console

Let's say we have an app in Google Play which supports in-app purchase of license.
Let the subscription model (existing) be like :

(a) Monthly Plan - $1/month

(b) Yearly Plan - $11/Year

Now, let's say, we want to decommission the existing plans and introduce two new plans

(c) Monthly - $1.2/month

(d) Yearly - $10/Year.

Now, my questions are -

1. What happens to the users who already active subscription with (a) OR (b)?
2. What happens after the subscription for (a) OR (b) has come to an end? Does the user automatically get changed to the newly introduced (c) OR (d) ? This ideally shouldn't happen and the user should get some kind of notification from PlayStore pointing out the price change. I want to know what is the exact behaviour in this case.
3. What happens when an active subscription for (a) OR (b) is cancelled? After cancellation can the user come back and still see the old subscription plans (a) OR (b)?